# How can I compute the income of the sellerId of the products?

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, mongoose, math

I'm trying to learn the advanced mongodb+mongoose function, so this is the result of my orders, and what I'm trying to do here is to compute **the total amounts related to the sellerId**

So in this one, I have two documents, the document 1 have an amount of 99 and and the other one is 11

so I need to get the sum of two. I've been searching and found the aggregate, but I can't figure out how I can combine the two documents.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6360d1d0bd860240e2589564",
        "userId": "6360cf687e186ebe29ab2a29",
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "6360cdd166480badb8c1e05b",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "6360c6ed05e1e99034b5f7eb",
                "_id": "6360d1d0bd860240e2589565"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 99,
        "location": "asdsad",
        "time": "asdsad",
        "status": "pending",
        "tax": 0.99,
       
    },
    {
        "_id": "6360d7978044f3048e59bf34",
        "userId": "6360d50dbd860240e258c585",
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "6360d7528044f3048e59bb6c",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "6360d4d5bd860240e258c582",
                "_id": "6360d7978044f3048e59bf35"
            },
            {
                "productId": "6360d7868044f3048e59bd8c",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "6360d4d5bd860240e258c582",
                "_id": "6360d7978044f3048e59bf36"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 11,
        "location": "Gym",
        "time": "8:00 AM",
        "status": "pending",
        "tax": 0.11,
      
    }
]
```

Comment: Combine documents using `$group`. Sum the amounts using `$sum` inside the `$group` step

Comment: so what will be my http , it should be.

`router.get('/income/:id(seller Id)')`

Answer (score 0):

This might helps.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```